# How can I send a GET request from my flask app to another site?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Originally, I tried to post an ajax request from my client side to a third party url, but it seems that the browser have security issues with that. I thought about sending an ajax to the server side, from there to send a GET request to the third party, get the response and send it back to the client side. How can I do that with flask?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Install the `requests` module (much nicer than using `urllib2`) and then define a route which makes the necessary request - something like:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/some-url')
def get_data():
    return requests.get('http://example.com').content
```

Depending on your set up though, it'd be better to configure your webserver to reverse proxy to the target site under a certain URL.

Comment: Using urllib2's request causes an error in my host, my guess is that installing request would do the same (didn't examined the traceback yet though)... Isn't there a built in flask function for that? @Jon Clements

Comment: @user1639431 nope - no builtin function - is Flask running under apache2/nginx ?

Comment: No idea, it's a cloud service, but my money is on nginx. Anyway, I looked at the traceback, and both urllib2 and requests give "connection refused". I have no problem to open/curl this url from my cli, can't understand the source of this problem. @Jon Clements

Comment: @user1639431 if you just use `requests.get('http://example.com')` do you get the same? (just to check there's no filtering based on User-Agent or something)

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error if using `requests.get("http://www.google.com")`. I can't seem to find an appropriate workaround. @Jon Clements

Comment: @user1639431 I'm guessing you have no control to the web server config... so that wouldn't be a viable route...

Comment: Don't forget to set the correct content type, ie:
`return Response(`
`requests.get('http://example.com').content,`
`mimetype='application/json')`

Comment: Has anybody found a solution against this error ?  requests and urllib2 produce it. I had thought that maybe Flask was catching the request made by `requests.get(...)` as if it was a request made by the client to the Flask app (which might have caused recursive calls to my `@app.route`s), but ... :/ Setting up some tests to find out does not lead me anywhere

Comment: I tried several urls (with or without http://), and even tried to produce recursive calls to the route (in order to determine if requests.get are working at all). Like `requests.get("localhost:5000/myroute")` but **this does not produce any recursive call to the route**. It seems like `requests.get(...)` and other fetches are just not working.

Comment: @Jon Clements how can i reuse TCP connection in this case? For example every time a new requesst comes, it would open a new TCP connection as we are not using request.Session. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: why use external library when you are using web framework such as flask? does flask not provide functionality for requests?

Answer (score 20):

Flask alone does not have this capability, but it is a simple matter to write a request handler that makes a request to another server using an HTTP client library and then return that response.

```
# third-party HTTP client library
import requests

# assume that "app" below is your flask app, and that
# "Response" is imported from flask.

@app.route("/proxy-example")
def proxy_example():
    r = requests.get("http://example.com/other-endpoint")
    return Response(
        r.text,
        status=r.status_code,
        content_type=r.headers['content-type'],
    )
```

However, this will not achieve exactly the same result as you might expect from a client-side request. Since your server cannot "see" any cookies that the client browser has stored for the target site, your proxied request will be effectively anonymous and so, depending on the target site, may fail or give you a  different response than you'd get requesting that resource in the browser.

If you have a relationship with the third-party URL (that is, if you control it or are able to work with the people who do) they can give access for cross-domain requests in the browser using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (which is only supported in modern browsers) or [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (an older workaround that predates CORS).

The third-party provider could also give you access to the data you want at an endpoint that is designed to accept requests from other servers and that provides a mechanism for you to authenticate your app. The most popular protocol for this is [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Comment: Have you tried running this example inside a running Flask app ? As well as other people trying to do fetches, I get errors like "requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for ..." (... == my target url).  I tried several sort of urls, from http://myurl.com to things like http://localhost:5000/myurl... but no request. And I even tried to do recursive call to the route to see if `requests.get()` would work (and trigger the route again), but even urls like `requests.get("localhost:5000/myroute")` do not cause recursive calls. It seems like requests just do not work...

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have stated using the requests module for python would be the best way to tackle this from the coding perspective.  However as the comments mentioned (and the reason I came to this question) this can give an error that the request was denied.  This error is likely cause by SELinux.

To check if this is the issue first make sure SELinux is enabled with this command:

```
sestatus
```

If 'Current Mode' is 'enforcing' then SELinux is enabled.

Next get the current bool values that apply directly to apache with this command:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

Look for the setting 'httpd_can_network_connect' this determines if apache is allowed to make TCP requests out to the network.  If it is on then all apache TCP requests will be allowed.  To turn it on run the following as root:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

If you only need database access (I had this problem before which is why I suspected SELinux here) then it would probably be better to only turn on 'httpd_cna_network_connect'.

The purpose of this policy is that if a hacker was to hijack your apache server they would not be able to get out through the server to the rest of your internal network.

This probably would've been better as a comment but I don't have enough rep..

Sources:
https://tag1consulting.com/blog/stop-disabling-selinux
https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain everything thoroughly.
A comment would have been insufficient to convey the information.