# Making GET requests from URLs with flask

Tags: python, flask

Making GET requests from urls can be done with the python requests library like this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://someapi.io/api/data")
response.json()
```

I'm currently trying to make GET requests from URLs with the flask request module but i can't find any useful information.

Comment: The `request` thread local proxy object in Flask and the `requests` library are two fundamentally different things and don't serve the same purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send a GET request from my flask app to another site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463004/how-can-i-send-a-get-request-from-my-flask-app-to-another-site)

Answer (score 0):

Flask is a server, the request object you can access on `flask.request` is the context of the request you received on the related API request.

Please see: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/

The requests library is not related and with this one, you can do all the GET requests you want.

You can do a request in one of your API requests handled by your flask server but you would have to use directly the request module and not the request object of the flask module.